# Add a Custom Tree Class in Java Language Hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, tree

I have designed a CustomTree class and programmed its operations.
Nodes are added such that a subtree will become full, before an element can be added to its sibling subtree.

Since Tree is a collection of nodes, I realized that, my CustomTree should implement a Collection Interface.

Is this correct or should my CustomTree extend a more relevant class like TreeSet?

I want to know where my class should go into if it should match Java's language heirarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is which properties do you want your class to have? Collection properties (just a general "bag"), Set properties (no two elements are the same) and/or List properties (sequence of elements is relevant)?

Once you have answered these questions for yourself, you can select the proper base class.

Comment: I believe, I should go with Collection, as I am allowing duplicates in my tree.

Comment: Then consider extending the AbstractCollection class instead of just implementing the interface. It should ease your task.

Comment: Can you please detail more on the advantages of AbstractCollection over Collection interface.
P.S I will google it though :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html
Basically, you only need to implement a subset of methods and will get the full interface.